# SSL + Apache + p7b file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, https

thanks for any help

I've received a folder from a client for an ssl that includes the following files:

```
1. name.csr    /*this shouldn't need to be used right?*/
2. file.p7b
3. cert.crt
```

I've installed too many certs in my time but never came across a p7b file. Normally i would config apache like the below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /path/to/web-host
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_my-site_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/custom.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_mysite_com.ca-bundle
DocumentRoot /path/to/web-host/
<Directory /path/to/web-host>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How i've tried:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/name.csr
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/file.p7b
```

This is giving a 500 error.

From my research ( one article - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193745/install-p7b-on-apache) says that you don't need to install the files?

To be honest i'm stumped as to how to set this up.

This guy (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306125/install-a-trusted-p7b-certificate-on-apache) says his problem was the cert wasn't signed by a trusted authority.

This is on ubuntu 16 by the way.

Would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: I’m not going to post this as an answer due to lack of details. But, the .csr is not used. The .p7b should not, and usually cannot, contain the private key. So the .p7b would be the certificate file and the .cer should be the key file. If you need to convert the p7b encoded file, you can do that online in several places or use OpenSSL. Just convert it to a .cer. The p7b should contain the chain files in one, so you don’t need the chain file config entry.

Comment: I think you're missing the private key. What is the header of the `.crt` file? Does it start with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` or `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`? If it's just garbage, then it's likely a `DER` formatted file instead of a `PEM` formatted one. You'd probably be best using `openssl` if it's `DER` encoded.